# PCRE make parameters optional

Tags: regex, preg-match, pcre

I'd like to match:

- /city-and-country-to-state/
- /city-and-country-to-state/nederland
- /city-and-country-to-state/nederland/amsterdam
- /city-and-country-to-state/Germany/übercity

I have this regex: `/city-and-country-to-state/(?<country>[\p{L}\s]+)/(?<city>[\p{L}\s]+)$)u`

Output of preg_match(regex, /city-and-country-to-state/nederland/amsterdam):

```
Array
(
    [0] => /city-and-country-to-state/nederland/amsterdam
    [country] => nederland
    [1] => nederland
    [city] => amsterdam
    [2] => amsterdam
)
```

How can I make both /country and /city optional?
I'd like to check that later and show the client a nice error when one of those params are missing.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional components:

```
^/city-and-country-to-state(?:/(?<country>[^/\n]+)(?:/(?<city>[^/\n]+))?)?/?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY5yY9/1)

**Code:**

```
preg_match_all(
   '~^/city-and-country-to-state(?:/(?<country>[^/]+)(?:/(?<city>[^/]+))?)?/?$~um',
   $input, $matches
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use something a bit more generic, like

```
/city-and-country-to-state(/[\p{L}\s]+)*
```

Then parse the resulting groups. If there's one, then treat it as a the country. If there's two, then treat the second as a city. If there's none, then show an error message.

This is also more extensible, as you can drive down to finer degrees of specificity without needing to re-invent your regex. For example, if you were to do something like this for the US, then you could use

```
/city-and-country-to-state/US/Atlanta
```

or, to specify a smaller city,

```
/city-and-country-to-state/US/California/Atlanta
/city-and-country-to-state/US/Idaho/Atlanta
/city-and-country-to-state/US/Texas/Atlanta
```

I'd guess that this probably doesn't make sense for your particular use-case (given that you seem to be resolving the state based on the country/city) but I'm generally a fan of *not* painting myself into a corner.